# Django internal server error when creating application

Tags: django

These are the steps I've done:

1. Create a virtual env
2. Create a new Django project
3. Enable the admin

When I had this ready, I successfully saw the admin login screen. No problems here.

But when I did:

1. Start application
2. Add this application in the installed applications tuple (settings.py)
3. Run syncdb or not (I've tried both)

I get internal server error every time I try to access the admin.
Do you have any idea why it's happening?

PS: I'm sorry if there is some configuration information missing, but I'm not a server expert.
Just ask and put them here.

Comment: Enable DEBUG=True in your settings and post the error message here.

Comment: It's enabled. Even though, the 500 happens.

Comment: OK. If you do not run the Django development server, than look at the logfile of the webserver you are using and post it here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some strange reason the Apache log didn't show me any error.
The workaround was adding two lines to a shell script that executes the CGI that actually runs Django in production version:

echo Content-type: text/plain
echo

Now I can see the error. (it was a missing cgitb module)

Answer (score 1):

The only way you are ever going to solve an `Internal Server Error` is by knowing what it is...

If you're running apache, check your logs (wherever you defined them to be) - often in `/var/log/apache2/error.log` If not - find your logs for your webserver.

Your app is somehow causing server errors (as opposed to python/django errors) - perhaps file permissions, libraries missing to load django/your app dependencies.